# How to give respective hyperlinks to respective images in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, image, hyperlink

Is there a way to add a hyperlink to each of the images so that when a user clicks a particular image, that the browser will navigate to a different URL? Each image would have a different url associated with it.

```
<?php 
    $display = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name, image_path FROM table_name"); 
    foreach($display as $displays){ 
?>
<img src ="<?php echo $display->image_path ; ?>"/>
<?php  }  ?>
```

So here I want to put a hyperlink for each image retrieved from the database, with the hyperlink navigating to a URL that displays the details about the image. How do I do it?

Comment: what is the hyperlink url you want to use..?

Answer (score 0):

image tag you cant add link , but you can put the image inside an anchor tag likewise,

```
$display_books  =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT bookname, image_path FROM book");

 foreach($display_books as $display)
 {
    <a href='<?php echo 'put your image_link dynamically ';?>' title='something'>
        <img src="<?php echo $display_books->image_path ; ?>"/>
    </a>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the associated link coming from db try this:

```
<?php 
 $display_books= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT bookname, image_path, image_link FROM book"); 

    foreach($display_books as $display){ ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $display->image_link?>">
             <img src="<?php echo $display->image_path ; ?>"/>
          </a>

<?php  }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
<?php 
    $display_books= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT bookname, image_path FROM book"); 
    foreach($display_books as $display){
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo 'your_image_details_url_here';?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $display->image_path ; ?>"/>
        </a>
    <?php  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just wrap each `img` tag in your loop in an `a` tag, with `href` pointing to the link URL you want.

Assuming you can get the url link information the same way you're getting the image path, it would look something like this:

```
<?php 
 $display_books= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT bookname, image_path, image_url_link FROM book"); 
    foreach($display_books as $display){ ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $display->image_url_link; ?>">
           <img src="<?php echo $display->image_path ; ?>"/>
         </a>
<?php  }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $display_books= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT bookname, image_path, Yourimage_hyperlink FROM book"); 
foreach($display_books as $display){ ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $display->Yourimage_hyperlink ; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $display->image_path; ?>"/></a>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 $display_books = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT bookname, image_path FROM book"); 
    foreach($display_books as $display){ ?>
         <a href="destination.php">
         <img style="border:0;" src ="<?php echo $display->image_path ; ?>" alt="HTML tutorial" width="42" height="42"/>
         </a>

<?php  }  ?>
```